# TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, geddy

I have a Node.js/Geddy app which was working untill a few minutes ago. Now, when I try to run it, I get the following error:

[image]

I have many models, but for one of them, I get this error.

The error is shown because in the file whose path is displayed in the console the following is undefined:

```
reg[ownedModelName]
```

where

```
reg = model.descriptionRegistry
```

and **ownedModelName** is given by

```
if (assnKey == 'belongsTo') {
        ownerModelName = modelName;
        ownedModelName = self.name;
        idKey = modelName;
      }
      else {
        ownerModelName = self.name;
        ownedModelName = modelName;
        idKey = self.name;
      }
```

Actually, I know the value of **ownedModelName**, but I don't know why **reg[ownedModelName]** is undefined.

This is how the model which triggers the error looks like:

```
var RenderingForm = function () {

 this.defineProperties({
    name: {type: 'string'},
    description: {type: 'string'},
    mode: {type: 'string'},
    helpText: {type: 'string'},
    noEvaluation: {type: 'boolean'},
    compatibleProblemTypes: {type: 'string'}
  });

  this.validatesPresent('name');
  this.validatesPresent('description');


};

RenderingForm = geddy.model.register('RenderingForm', RenderingForm);
```

Why is that undefined and how can I solve my problem?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to create the same app on another partition, it didn't work, and now when I've tried again to run the old app, I get the same error, but for another model than before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!!! Thanks to [THIS](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/geddyjs/uoDPUTSMK8M) I've found out that it was a hasOne() or has Many() with a wrong parameter.